# Sympy failing to solve simple trig equations

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations, and am having some weird behavior. Below, I've boiled things down to the simplest case that fails for me. The equations I'm trying to solve are in the variables `f` and `theta`, with a parameter `g`:

1. `f*sin(theta) == 0`
2. `f*cos(theta) - g == 0`

My Sympy code is below, which fails to find any solution. I verify that a solution exists (`theta=0`, `f=g`) in the code as well. There are two 'tricks' I can use to get the solver to work: first, set `g=1` (but I'd like to solve in terms of the parameter). Alternatively, using `e2alt` instead of `e2` yields a useful equation.

```
from sympy import *

g = symbols('g', Positive=True)
f = symbols('f', Real=True)
theta = symbols('theta', Real=True)

e1 = f*sin(theta) 
e2 = f*cos(theta) - g
e2alt = f*(cos(theta) - g/f) 

equations = [e1, e2]
# equations = [e1, e2alt]  # using this actually works
variables = [theta, f]
soln = solve(equations, 
              variables, 
              dict=True)

print('Equations:')
print(equations)
print('Found solutions:')
print(soln)

handSoln = {theta:0, f:g}
print('Hand-found solutions')
print(handSoln)
print('Evaluating at hand-found solutions')
print([eq.subs(handSoln) for eq in equations])
```

Edit -- for clarity, my question is: how can I get sympy to successfully solve such equations? The actual problems I am working with are more complicated than the above, and I want the solutions automatically, without digging into each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lowercase assumptions `real`, not `Real`, etc... and then rewrite your equations in terms of exponentials:

```py
>>> solve([i.rewrite(exp) for i in equations], variables, dict=True)
[{f: -g, theta: pi}, {f: g, theta: 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Also for my more complex original problem, that had more angles, parameters, etc. Do you know why this (the `rewrite(exp)` trick) isn't automatically done by sympy?

Comment: I think it is used in the single equation case, but not for systems of equations. I was surprised that this didn't work, too.